# Meaning of 'steel picture racks'

Tags: meaning

"But we'll get a classification and teletype it to Washington some time tonight. If it don't click, you'll be in for a day on the **steel picture racks** downstairs."

A conversation between police officer and Philip Marlow the detective at the police
headquarters. The police says he is sending a fingerprints of dead person to further
investigation to Washington (the novel was written in 1938,  'Red Wind' by Chandler).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it means that they would have to laboriously go through their collection of criminals' fingerprints, presumably kept in racks (frames) made of steel. I envision a smaller version of the kind of flip-racks that are used to display and preserve maps, or to display posters in a store.